# How to package and deploy serverless framework code in separate steps?

Tags: serverless-framework

My question is about separate package/deploy steps. What I want to do is to package the service at step 1 of the deployment process, then copy the content of the package to another machine and deploy from there. Can't make it work. I use no parameters, and "serverless package" seems to work fine (creates ".serverless" folder without an attempt to deploy), but when I copy the ".serverless" folder to another location and execute 'serverless deploy" it only says "packaging service" and does nothing. Is this how deployment of a package supposed to work? This happens on a vanilla aws node service.

Answer (score 0):

The command `serverless deploy --package path-to-package` seems to be what you are looking for, as specified in the [Serverless Framework documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/#deploying-a-package).

> This deployment option takes a deployment directory that has already been created with serverless package and deploys it to the cloud provider. This allows you to easier integrate CI / CD workflows with the Serverless Framework.

You were probably missing the `--package` option.

Comment: This currently does not work.  At least not for Google Cloud Functions.  See the first comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390027/using-sls-deploy-package-doesn-t-work-with-serverless-for-google-cloud-function.