# Using sls deploy –package doesn’t work with serverless for google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I was following the quick start guide for serverless https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/quick-start/ and created a service as mentioned in the guide. I ran the following commands:

```
serverless create --template google-nodejs --path my-service
cd my-service
npm install
```

I edited the serverless.yml to contain a valid key path and tried the following command

```
serverless package
```

A .serverless folder was created with myservice.zip file in it. Later I tried to deploy this myservice.zip file using

```
serverless deploy --package <absolute path of myservice.zip file>
```

The command failed with the following error:
The path argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined

I am wondering if I missed something or serverless doesn’t support deploy --package option for google cloud functions.

My serverless version is 1.44.1

My actual use case is to deploy a prepackaged zipped file to google cloud functions using serverless

Comment: It looks like only --config or -c are allowed as options for deploy for now. https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/cli-reference/deploy/